# Attatch background image to bottom of sizechanging divs

Tags: html, css, background, position

I have defined a number of divs, which have partly transparent backgrounds wich are overlapping each others, I want to attatch one of them to to bottom of the div. However, if I add content to the divs, the background is attatched where I had specified the min-height. This occurs in all Browsers except IE.
This is my code:

```
#content1 {
    background-image: url(image/main_background.png);
    margin-left: 12px;
    margin-right: 12px;
    /*margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-left-width: 3px;
    border-right-width: 3px;
    border-top-width: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
    border-color: #000000;
    width: 976px;
    min-height: 355px;
    float: left;    
    }
#content2 {
    background-image: url(image/top_gradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    width: 976px;
    min-height: 355px;
    }
#content3 {
    background-image: url(image/bottom_gradient.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: 0% 100%;
    width: 976px;
    min-height: 355px;
    }
#content4 {
    background-image: url(image/top_background.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 976px;
    min-height: 355px;
    clear: both;
    }
```

and

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="content1"><div id="content2"><div id="content3"><div id="content4">
        <div id="content_elements">
            <::content::>
        </div>
        <div id="sidebar_elements">
            <::sidebar::>
        </div>
    </div></div></div></div>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean adding the content dynamically (after the div has been rendered) using JavaScript? Or does this happen even if you add content to the HTML of the page?

Comment: It happens when I add content that is larger then the min-height.

Answer (score 0):

Does this works: `background: url('background.png') no-repeat bottom;` so add **bottom** after **no-repeat**.

Comment: or if you want to split it into separate attributes, in the style the OP has used, `bottom` would be the value of `background-position`.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the point on split that, he can do it in one line.

Comment: Doesn't change a think. I used: background: url(image/bottom_gradient.png) repeat-x right bottom;

Comment: Try and add max-height: and see if that works. Or provide us with some live example.

Comment: Max height doesn't change anything, the only way I can influence where the actual background is positioned seems to be height and min-height. But I have content of different size, which shall be presentet in that box, therefore I cant use height... I will upload the whole page somewhere so you can have a look at it.